# Replacing View in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to replace a View in a LinearLayout programmatically. I tried the following method:

```
public void drawView() {
    //remove previous view, if exists
    if(((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartView)).getChildCount() > 0) {
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartView)).removeAllViewsInLayout();
    }

    //generate new view
    CustomView view = new CustomView(this,parameters);

    //add new view to layout
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayout)).addView(view);
}
```

The LinearLayout that this method refers to is defined in XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linLayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

The view is drawn correctly the first time (when there is no view yet in the LinearLayout. But the second time drawView is called, the previous View gets removed, but no new view added. How can I replace this programmatically generated view programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are removing from this layout `((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartView)).removeAllViewsInLayout();`
but adding to this: `((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayout)).addView(view);`

replace `R.id.linLayout` with `R.id.chartView`